# Telerik GridViewComboBoxColumn selection changed event triggering on RadGridView scrolling

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I'm working on a WPF application which is using Telerik controls.
I have a RadGridView which has a GridViewComboBoxColumn to show my users.
Now, I've registered a selection changed event in the code behind file in constructor as below:

```
> rgvMEO.AddHandler(RadComboBox.SelectionChangedEvent, new System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventHandler(OnSelectionChanged));

The problem I'm facing here is when I scroll my RadGridView horizontally, the above mentioned event handler (OnSelectionChanged) is being called. Also, PFB the xaml code:

> <telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn x:Name="colPrimaryReviewer"
                                                Header="Primary Reviewer"
                                                HeaderTextAlignment="Center"
                                                IsFilterable="True"
                                                EditTriggers="CellClick"
                                                ItemsSource="{Binding PrimaryReviewerList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                                                DataMemberBinding="{Binding PrimaryReviewerDisplayName, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                                DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName"                                                
                                                UniqueName="colPR" 
                                                IsReadOnly="False"
                                                CellStyle="{StaticResource GridViewCellStylePR}" />
```

and PFB the xaml code of RadGridView:

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="rgvMEO"
                         MinWidth="1000"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                         VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                         controls:ChildViewService.IsMainRadGridViewElement="True"
                         IsFilteringAllowed="True"
                         IsReadOnly="False"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding MonthEndOverrideList, Mode=TwoWay}"
                         SelectionMode="Extended"
                         ShowColumnFooters="True">
```

Comment: The event is raised when the `ComboBox` is loaded, which may also happen when you scroll it into view after it has previously being scrolled out of the view. Why don't you handle your selection change logic in the setter of the data-bound `PrimaryReviewerDisplayName` property?

Comment: Yes, that is definitely an option. I think i should try to sort out the bad code. Thanks for the suggestion :)